# Can Python version message be suppressed for child processes (Windows)?

Tags: python, windows, python-multiprocessing

I am using `multiprocessing` to calculate a large mass of data; i.e. I periodically spawn a process so that the total number of processes is equal to the number of CPU's on my machine.
I periodically print out the progress of the entire calculation... but this is inconveniently interspersed with Python's welcome messages from each child!
To be clear, this is a **Windows specific problem** due to how multiprocessing is handled.

E.g.

```
> python -q my_script.py

Python Version: 3.7.7 on Windows
```

Then many subsequent duplicates of the same version message print; one for each child process.
How can I suppress these?

I understand that if you run Python on the command line with a **`-q`** flag, it suppresses the welcome message; though I don't know how to translate that into my script.

**EDIT:**

I tried to include the interpreter flag `-q` like so:

`multiprocessing.set_executable(sys.executable + ' -q')`

Yet to no avail. I receive a `FileNotFoundError` which tells me I cannot pass options this way due to how they check arguments.

Anyways, here is the relevant section of code (It's an entire function):

```
def _parallelize(self, buffer, func, cpus):
    ## Number of Parallel Processes ##
    cpus_max = mp.cpu_count()
    cpus = min(cpus_max, cpus) if cpus else int(0.75*cpus_max)

    ## Total Processes to-do ##
    N = ceil(self.SampleLength / DATA_MAX)  # Number of Child Processes
    print("N: ", N)
    q = mp.Queue()  # Child Process results Queue

    ## Initialize each CPU w/ a Process ##
    for p in range(min(cpus, N)):
        mp.Process(target=func, args=(p, q)).start()

    ## Collect Validation & Start Remaining Processes ##
    for p in tqdm(range(N)):
        n, data = q.get()  # Collects a Result

        i = n * DATA_MAX  # Shifts to Proper Interval

        buffer[i:i + len(data)] = data  # Writes to open HDF5 file

        if p < N - cpus:  # Starts a new Process
            mp.Process(target=func, args=(p + cpus, q)).start()
```

**SECOND EDIT:**

I should probably mention that I'm doing everything within an anaconda environment.

Comment: How are you spawning a subprocess in a way that causes the welcome message to be printed?

Comment: Maybe redefine the environnement variable that point to python exe as python -q will work? Can you try?

Comment: If you edit your question and add the relevant code snippet where you exactly spawn the process, it would be very helpful. Normally, you have something like `args=(...,)` you can fill. But it's hard to guess without seeing what you have done so far.

Comment: have you take a look to that function : multiprocessing.set_executable()? Maybe you can pass the -q param from here

Comment: When I run code with multiprocessing.Process, I don't get a welcome message in the output.  I'm running on a Mac, and have run similar code on Linux.  All I can think of is that this is a Windows thing, and that your system is set up to act differently than most...to somehow have a welcome message printed as part of Python starting up a second process.  I'm pretty darn sure this isn't standard Python behavior.

Comment: I just ran the trivial example given in the docs for the Process() class (https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html).  All I get as output is "hello bob".

Comment: This looks like you are rewriting a `multiprocessing.Pool`. Is there any particular reason why you are not using that?

Comment: @RolandSmith The calculated datasets are sometimes several GBs. It's nice to write them to disk as they are being calculated.

Comment: @Steve Windows can't fork() processes; instead it has to spawn a new instance of the Python interpreter. I appreciate the input, though you may like to read into the difference.

Comment: @kaya3 Sorry for the late response. I edited the question.

Comment: @colidyre Excuse the delay. Check again.

Comment: @AronLloyd Although `Pool` workers generally return their processed data, there is nothing that prevents them from writing data to disk. For example, sometimes I have the worker just return a 2-tuple of the name/number of the item they've worked on and a `bool` to indicate whether it was processed succesfully. The processed data itself is directly written to disk.

Answer (score 0):

The message is printed on interactive startup.

A spawned process *does* inherit some flags from the child process.
But looking at the code in `multiprocessing` it does not seem possible to *change* these parameters from within the program.

So the easiest way to get rid of the messages should be to add the `-q` option to the original `python`  invocation that starts your program.
I have confirmed that the `-q` flag is inherited.

So that should suppress the message for the original process and the children that it spawns.

**Edit:**
If you look at the implementation of `set_executable`, you will see that you cannot add or change arguments that way. :-(

**Edit2:**
You wrote:

> I'm doing everything within an anaconda environment.

You you mean a virtual environment, or some kind of fancy IDE like spyder?

If you *ever* have a Python problem, first try reproducing  it in *plain CPython*, running from the command line. IDE's and fancy environments like anaconda sometimes do weird things when running Python.

Comment: I am not using interactive mode (that implies either running python without a script or passing the -i flag).
I have also tried this: `python -q myscript.py` from the command line.
It seems to have worked for you, am I doing something different? Thanks for taking the time!

Comment: My computers run FreeBSD UNIX instead of ms-windows, so I don't have this problem. This is specific to how `multiprocessing` must work on ms-windows.